# Using readme.md as the default page in a folder

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am using GitHub Pages as my website. I expect it to be accessed both via GitHub as well as a normal HTML static website. This means that the links must be compatible to both accesses. All the content is being created using md files.

Within docs I have folders, say `documentation`, `apis` etc. And within it a number of md files. I require one of them to be the default. Earlier, when I used index.md, it converted into index.html when we access the site as: `https://example.com/documentation` but from within GitHub if I click on the documentation folder it would not show up like it would do with readme.md. Hence I renamed the default md file in each folder to readme.md.

Now, obviously on the website if I type the URL: `https://example.com/documentation`, it gives a page not found error.

Is there a setting available in config.yml where I specify that readme.md is the default file of a directory? Alternatively, is there another solution to my need: viz. Clicking on the folder in GitHub should display the page as well as referring to the folder via HTML should display the same page in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround would be to symlink `index.md` to `readme.md`, that way, during the GitHub Pages HTML generation, you would still get `index.html`.

But your github.com navigation would display the `readme.md` file.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. Didn't think of that approach. I was hoping that there will be some frontmatter option that may work. I tried using `permalink: index.html` but it didn't work. Let me try your approach and update this question.